# How to user aggregate function with left join ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, aggregate

I have this query :

```
SELECT business.bussId, COUNT(invoices.userId) as invoices, COUNT(rating.bussId) as ratingCount ,
       FROM business
       LEFT JOIN invoice ON (invoice.bussId = business.bussId AND invoice.userId = '3000' )
       LEFT JOIN rating ON (rating.bussId = business.bussId )
       WHERE business.bussId=100
```

The COUNT(invoices.userId) user supposed to return the number of rows at invoices tables, where userId = 3000 AND bussId = 100.
in other words this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as invoice FROM `invoices` WHERE bussId = '100' AND userId = '30000'.
```

the second query return COUNT (*) = 3 and the first query (when I user LEFT JOIN) it's return 15, How to fix that ?

Comment: move `invoice.userId = '3000'` as where condition .

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, there is already, in on clause

Comment: I think you need another join for rating? Try `inner join`

Comment: @vp_arth since OP is using `AND invoice.userId = '3000'` condition in `left outer join ... on...` so it might create problem. if it was an `inner join` then you might be correct.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty that doesn't help, I get invoice = 15

Comment: @vp_arth could you write your suggested query

Comment: Hmm i presume the left join is the issue.. try using `inner join` instead

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I can't user inner join, because if I use INNER join, so I will not get details FROM business Table, When there is no bussId on the invoices table.

Comment: your query won't work because you invoice, and rating tables will return different result sets. One might have 15 results, and the other 3 results, both COUNT() on your first query will return 15 (i think)

Comment: @Shide how to fix it ?.

Comment: i would use cross apply. Let me write an answer

Comment: You need to count the occurances of each row. Possibly _COUNT(DISTINCT invoices.id)_ (assuming invoices.id is unique for the invoices table). You probably have 3 invoices and 5 ratings, giving 3 x 5 = 15 rows at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below query:

```sql
SELECT 
    business.bussId, 
    (SELECT COUNT(invoices.userId) 
        FROM invoice 
        WHERE invoice.bussId = a.bussId 
          AND invoice.userId = '3000') as invoices, 
    (SELECT COUNT(rating.bussId) 
        FROM rating 
        WHERE rating.bussId = a.bussId) as ratingCount
FROM business a
WHERE business.bussId=100
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but How could I select count and sum from the invoice in one query, I mean : SELECT business.bussId, (select count(invoices.userId),sum(invoice.price) from invoice where invoice.bussId = a.bussId AND invoice.userId = '3000' ) as invoices, (select COUNT(rating.bussId) from rating where rating.bussId = a.bussId ) as ratingCount ,
       FROM business a
              WHERE business.bussId=100

Comment: For sum you have to write another sub query because sub query must return single value..

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted any test data or any table declares so this is making assumptions on those.

You current query will get every combination of invoice and rating for a business. Hence if there are 3 invoices and 5 ratings that will result in 15 combinations of those.

Often this could be fixed by using COUNT(DISTINCT ), but you are counting the number of user ids for invoices, when that is a constant.

Assuming your invoice table and rating table both have unique keys called id then you should be able to change the counts to counting distinct on those fields:-

```
SELECT business.bussId, COUNT(DISTINCT invoices.id) as invoices, COUNT(DISTINCT rating.id) as ratingCount 
FROM business
LEFT JOIN invoice ON (invoice.bussId = business.bussId AND invoice.userId = '3000' )
LEFT JOIN rating ON (rating.bussId = business.bussId )
WHERE business.bussId = 100
```

This avoids using sub queries, which depending on the data can often perform badly. Although in this case it looks like you may be returning only a single row so this is not likely to be an issue

**EDIT**

To get the sum of the prices as well, this uses a sub query to get the count of invoices and the sum of the prices and then joins that to the business table:-

```
SELECT business.bussId, invoice_count as invoices, invoice_price, COUNT(DISTINCT rating.id) as ratingCount 
FROM business
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT bussId, COUNT(id) AS invoice_count, SUM(price) AS invoice_price
    FROM invoice
    WHERE userId = '3000'
    GROUP BY bussId
) invoice_sub
ON invoice_sub.bussId = business.bussId 
LEFT JOIN rating ON (rating.bussId = business.bussId )
WHERE business.bussId = 100
GROUP BY business.bussId, invoices, invoice_price
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, with count that's works fine,but How could I do SUM(invoices.price) ?

Comment: You can't directly. You would need to use a sub query to get the SUM.